# Multiple images aren't shown from squeezed 1d array in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to reshape images that are currently squeezed in 1d array

e.g 10000 images represented as (10000, 3072)

I am trying to do the following

```
def _show_images(images, cols=5, titles=None):
    assert ((titles is None) or (len(images) == len(titles)))
    n_images = len(images)
    if titles is None: titles = ['Image (%d)' % i for i in range(1, n_images + 1)]
    fig = plt.figure()
    for n, (image, title) in enumerate(zip(images, titles)):
        a = fig.add_subplot(cols, np.ceil(n_images / float(cols)), n + 1)
        if image.ndim == 2:
            plt.gray()
        plt.imshow(image)
        a.set_title(title)
    fig.set_size_inches(np.array(fig.get_size_inches()) * n_images)
    plt.show()

def show_images(data, labels, cl):
    data = data.reshape[data.shape[0], 32, 32, 3] 
    _show_images(data)
```

Why am I not seeing pictures displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reshape` is a function, not an array. Try `data = data.reshape((data.shape[0], 32, 32, 3))`

Comment: anyway, yeah I was dumb